# jquery - div onclick - not working in iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, onclick

i tried different ways. 
I need **onclick for a div with jquery in my mobile site. On clicking on the div it will send an ajax call.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
... ......
```

> **$('body').on('click','.selectableCard', function() {**

```
    $.ajax({
                url : URL}).done(
                function(data) {    .....    ....   });
        });
...
....
        });
```

This is working fine in desktop browsers and in android emulator. **But not working in iPode4**.

**Div**

```
<div class="resultsMainContainer selectableCard  ">
```

style

```
.selectableCard {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}
.resultsMainContainer {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #CCCCCC;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 98%;
}
```

I tried as:

```
$('.selectableCard').click(
        function(){....
```

But it's not working in desktop itself. !

Any idea would be appreciated :)

Here is an updated jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/smilyface/y7DX5/1/

**Will work fine in desktop , but not working in iPod**

Comment: not sure that the $(document).ready( works on mobiles

Comment: document ready works fine in mobile. Because i used it in another pages in the same application.

Comment: should you have $('body') in quotes? shouldn't it be $(body)

Comment: Liam, it has a single quote. 'body'

Comment: ah my mistake just looked it up my self. What version of jquery are you using and are you using jquery mobile for your mobile sites or just jquery?

Comment: it's just jquery :(

actually i dont know exactly. Somebody has changed the filename to jquery.js ! But the commented line at the first part of the file shows "jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.2". I think it is not mobile-jquery. (searched for the word 'mobile'. Not found)

Comment: is the site live? if so can we have the URL?

Comment: also on your desktop have you tried it on safari to see if it is safari mobile that isn't working?

Comment: 1.Site is not yet in live. sorry for that. 2. I have windows  and LinuxCentOS. Will try installing safari in windows. thanx for the suggestion.

Comment: Liam, Tried in Safari + windows Desktop. Its working fine there too !!

Comment: can you put this in jsfiddle and i will take a look later tonight

Comment: Thanks in advance :) http://jsfiddle.net/smilyface/y7DX5/

Comment: Updated one : http://jsfiddle.net/smilyface/y7DX5/1/

Comment: You got a Typo try this  

$('.container .selectableCard').on('click', function (e) {  
  
you wrote  
.selectablecard not  
.selectableCard

Comment: @ThomasNordquist , i think itz correct there. I didnt see any typo.

Comment: And yea. Itz working fine in desktop browser. You cant see any error in your computer. That is the main problem !

Comment: @smilyface just check it with an iPhone and iOS7, works on iOS7 charming - as i recall you can set your Safari on iOS to developer mode... it is somwhere in Settings -> Safari -> 
But it seems like you need Safari on Mac (maybe it works with Windows to)

 - typo: i just saw your first jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it working.**

I just put the entire onclick function (onclick selectableCard) inside the ajax.
So that it will run each time when the ajax loads. Thus it can get the class/div specified inside the jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
            url : URL
            }).done(
            function(data) {

                container.html(data); //innerHTML part
                $('.selectableCard').click(function(){..call div came through above innerHTML..});
});
```

Answer (score 11):

On iphone you must use `touchevent` for exemple:

```
$('.selectableCard').on('click touchstart',function(){
//your code
});
```

Comment: I couldn't try this because of a technical problem(server down). Anyway I got the answer. I am posting that here. Thanks for the support

Comment: This works perfectly for me and looks like a really good answer